# Python Pandas compare strings in data frame row excluding empty string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a data frame that i would like to compare string values in same row. Row includes empty strings also.
Following code makes the job but unfortunately return True when both strings are "None" i.e. empty strings

```
Col = list(ENTITY.columns.values)
for i in combinations(Col,2):
    df[i[0]+' to '+i[1]+' dedication'] =df.apply(lambda row: row[i[0]] == row[i[1]],axis=1)
    df[i[0]+' to '+i[1]+' dedication'] = np.where(df[i[0]+' to '+i[1]+' dedication'], 'Y', 'N')
```

---

For instance, if `row[i[0]] == "AAA1" and row[i[1]] == "AAA1"` the output will be `True`, but if `row[i[0]] == "AAA1" and row[i[1]] == None` or if `row[i[0]] == None and row[i[1]] == None` the output will be False.

How can i resolve this issue when True statement will be when both strings are not empty and matched?
Is it possible to use operators isinstance and basestring in lambda function?
Desired output:
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Can you add data sample and desired output with problematic data?

Comment: For instance, if row[i[0]] == "AAA1" and row[i[1]] == "AAA1" the output will be True, but if row[i[0]] == "AAA1" and row[i[1]] == None or if row[i[0]] == None and row[i[1]] == None the output will be False.

Comment: Sample data means a small amount of data so that we can replicate and subsequently solve the problem.

Comment: Your code gives that output for me... Would need to see what `df` is to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`pandas.notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) or [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) for compare with `None` (or compare with `NaN`):

```
df.apply(lambda row: (row[i[0]] == row[i[1]]) and 
                      pd.notnull(row[i[0]]) and 
                      pd.notnull(row[i[1]), axis=1)
```

But better is compare columns, then it working perfectly, because `np.nan != np.nan`:

```
for i in combinations(Col,2):
    df[i[0]+' to '+i[1]+' dedication'] = np.where(df[i[0]] == df[i[1]], 'Y', 'N')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key':[1,2,3,4],
                   'SCANNER A':['AAA1', None, None, 'AAA1'],
                   'SCANNER B':['AAA1', 'AAA2', None, 'AAA2']})

df['new'] = np.where(df['SCANNER A'] == df['SCANNER B'], 'Y', 'N')
print (df)
   Key SCANNER A SCANNER B new
0    1      AAA1      AAA1   Y
1    2      None      AAA2   N
2    3      None      None   N
3    4      AAA1      AAA2   N
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `NaN != NaN`, so if those are stored as an empty value, a simple comparison should suffice. If you store them as `'None` (a String)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['a', None, None, 'a', 'a'], 'col2': ['a', 'a', None, None, 'b']})
```

> ```
>   col1        col2
> 0     a       a
> 1     None    a
> 2     None    None
> 3     a       None
> 4     a       b
> ```

```
df_result = df.copy()
for (col1_label, col1), (col2_label, col2) in itertools.combinations(df.iteritems(), 2):
    df_result[col1_label + '_' + col2_label] = col1 == col2
```

> ```
>       col1    col2    col1_col2
> 0     a       a       True
> 1     None    a       False
> 2     None    None    False
> 3     a       None    False
> 4     a       b       False
> ```

2 small tips

- You can simplify your loop with `iteritems`, no need to use the indices
- I try to keep the results of my calculations in a different DataFrame than my initial data and intermediary results. This way it is easier to troubleshoot what went wrong and start over halfway. I only reuse the original DataFrame when memory is an issue

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic here is simple replace the empty strings with **numpy.nan**

**>>>numpy.nan == numpy.nan**

**False**

```
import numpy as np
ENTITY.replace(to_replace="None",value=np.nan,inplace=True)
# your code below
```